# Successful when executing VS 2005 project in Debug mode but failed in MinRelease mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I developed a ClassLibrary in VC++ using VS 2005.

Later I registered the dll, i got from building the project in **MinRelease mode** and when i tried to execute my application it failed.

But the same application got executed successfully by registering the dll that i got from building the project in **Debug mode**

What is the issue.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/releasemode.aspx

Comment: i found this link useful while searching for a solution